# LINQ to SQL insertonsubmit() does not work (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have problem with my desktop application in c#. I decided to migrate my very simple web application in web forms to windows forms. I used sql and LINQ. In web forms everything worked fine. Now in windows forms no. Code is exactly the same. I change it to only one control and one table in database. I debbuged and i think everything is fine but from some reason insertonsubmit() command doesnt work. I will be grateful for help.

I use Windows 8, Visual for web 2012, for desktop 2013

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        osoba obj = new osoba();

        obj.nazwa ="Anna";

        db.osobas.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
}
```

in attachment project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nHhrRU4CjHZExDMFRlNkZzN0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: What happens? Does item not saved or there is some exception, or something else?

Comment: I don't get any errors. But from some reason data is not saved. I'm beginner in programming in c# and I'm not best in analyzing errors. In attachment is my simple project to test. Thanks

Comment: Where your database is saved? On local DB server or within project itself? If it saved in the project folder, then with each build it will be recreated anyway

Comment: Yes I have  database attached in project. I cereted it by clicking in server explorer "add connetion", then choose "Miicrosoft SQL Server database file". In web forms my apllication works

Comment: Yes, because web application hasn't debug folder where DB is copied. But WinForms has it, so on each build your DB is overwrited by DB from project. If execute your project manually from bin\debug folder, then it won't be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Convert comment as answer.

The issue was that when you have DB attached in the project, for web application it works fine, as it doesn't copy it to bin folder. But for Win applications it copies it on each build, so in your case steps were:

1. when you run it from Visual Studio,
2. it do build, and copy compiled assemblies and DB itself into bin\Debug folder
3. then it starts your application. all changes are made in the db from bin\Debug folder
4. then when you run it again from Visual Studio
5. it again do build, and copy compiled assemble and the same old DB that exists in project. And this steps is overrides previous DB from bin\Debug folder
6. and when application starts it hasn't any changes from step 3

It's typical issue when you use DB in attached to the project. And usually it's ok, but if you don't like it, you can move your database away from the project. Or you can just use SQL Express or usual SQL server and attach your DB to SQL Server, and then it will be separated from your project, and won't be replaced each time.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error few seconds ago but it was fixed.

There is solution your database connection in visual studio 2013.

Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> yourdatabasename should turn green color.

Also you can check whether your tables has primary key or not.

I hope it is helpful.